# How to print all the elements of an array into file using bash

Tags: arrays, bash, awk, sed

I have an array of element in one variable. I have to print all the values of the array into a file. Initially, I read the values of an array from many files using **sed and cut**. I have print those values(**array**) into a file. When I use print statement within loop, the values are overwritten. Is there any other way to print all the elements into a file using commands like awk or cat???
Here is the code which I tried

```
for ((GPCount=0; GPCount< $GPCnt; GPCount++))  
do
G=${GPArr[$GPCount]}
G="$(sed -n '2p' $file.txt|cut -d" " -f7)"
printf "%d\n" "$G" >$out.txt
done
```

I know if I  use this in loop it will overwrite, so I tried another block of code

```
for ((GPCount=0; GPCount< $GPCnt; GPCount++))  
do
$GPArr[$GPCount]="$(sed -n '2p' $file.txt|cut -d" " -f7)"
done
printf "%d\n" "${GPArr[@]}" >$out2.txt
```

there is no output and I am getting error( its giving the value but it couldnt direct the sed o/p to array variable

```
./test.sh: line 33: =33: command not found
./test.sh: line 33: =39: command not found
./test.sh: line 33: =45: command not found
```

If I modify the code like this

```
 for ((GPCount=0; GPCount< $GPCnt; GPCount++))  
 do
 G="$(sed -n '2p' $file.txt|cut -d" " -f7)"
 done
 printf "%d\n" "${GPArr[@]}" >$out2.txt
```

I am getting 0 as a output in the text file. I need the o/p like this in my text file

```
33
39
45
```

Kindly help me in this regard. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

```
printf "%d\n" "$G" >>$out.txt
```

or

```
echo "$G" >>$out.txt
```

`>` will overwrite your whole file, while `>>` will append to the file

Usage:

```
for ((GPCount=0; GPCount< $GPCnt; GPCount++))  
do
G=${GPArr[$GPCount]}
G="$(sed -n '2p' $file.txt|cut -d" " -f7)"
printf "%d\n" "$G" >>$out.txt
done
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to accomplish your task is to use the `bash` builtin `printf` command. Note: this is `bash` builtin `printf`, not `/usr/bin/printf`.

```
for ((GPCount=0; GPCount< $GPCnt; GPCount++))  
do
printf -v GPArr[$GPCount] "%d" $(sed -n '2p' $file.txt|cut -d" " -f7)
done
printf "%d\n" "${GPArr[@]}" >$out2.txt
```

Give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

Your first loop fails because you seem to be trying to use `G` as an alias for `${GPArr[$GPCount]}`. `bash` variables don't work that way (although in `bash` 4.3, you *can* declare a *nameref* which would work:

```
for ((GPCount=0; GPCount< $GPCnt; GPCount++))  
do
    declare -n G=${GPArr[$GPCount]}
    G="$(sed -n '2p' $file.txt|cut -d" " -f7)"
    printf "%d\n" "$G"
done > "$out.txt"
```

Also, make sure you aren't overwriting the file `$out.txt` each time through the loop.
)

Your second loop just has a typo; you don't prefix a variable *assignment* with a dollar sign.

```
for ((GPCount=0; GPCount< $GPCnt; GPCount++))  
do
    # Not $GPArr[$GPCOUNT]=...
    GPArr[$GPCount]="$(sed -n '2p' $file.txt|cut -d" " -f7)"
done
printf "%d\n" "${GPArr[@]}" >$out2.txt
```

Incidentally, you don't need a loop counter at all; you can append to an array with the `+=` operator.

```
for ((GPCount=0; GPCount< $GPCnt; GPCount++))  
do
    # Not $GPArr[$GPCOUNT]=...
    GPArr+=("$(sed -n '2p' $file.txt|cut -d" " -f7)")
done
printf "%d\n" "${GPArr[@]}" >$out2.txt
```

(In any case, it's not clear how the `sed` call is producing different values each time through the loop.)